# How do I get the mean of these variables..... What is the arithmetic function?

Tags: java

How can I write a method to calculate the average of some numbers?

```
public class MyCalculator {

    int input1 = 10;
    int input2 = 20;
    int input3 = 30;
    int input4 = 40;
    int input5 = 50;

    public float average() {
        // TODO: write java code to calculate the average for all input variables
           
         return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your attempts. --- Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for something like this, which uses the new `Stream` library.

```
import java.util.stream.*;

class MyCalculator {
    public static double average(int[] input) {
        return IntStream.of(arr).average().getAsDouble();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        System.out.println(average(input));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
30.0
```

Comment: For a questioner who is at a beginner level (no criticism implied here) where they need help writing a simple expression involving addition and division, jumping to a stream-based solution is not appropriate.  One needs to understand the basics first.